# adding Linux users from php

Tags: php

can you please tell a way to add linux user from a php script ?
I am trying system and exec ...but I am not able to do..
please tell me if its possible or not ? and also if possible share the code snippet :)

thanks

Comment: You tried `exec('useradd Bill')`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that, but not in a simple way which is also secure and easy. PHP and Apache will never allow you to execute system commands out of the box, not to mention root stuff!

So you will need to study that, create some wrapper scripts which will be able to receive parameters from PHP (to know what to do, get the username and password of the new user, etc...) elevate their privileges (hint: look at sudo or SUID), and then run your command...

Comment: Thanks for reply..Iam really not concerned about the security in this case because I will be the only one accessing it..(I run apache on different port and will turn on apache only needed ) , will running apache as root user makes things easier ?